# Why was my flag on this non-answer "disputed"?

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderation

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172569/which-real-historical-figures-have-been-recreated-on-the-holodeck) specifically asks about **historic characters created on the holodeck**.

> *I was unable to find a definitive list, so I would like to know how many actual Earth history figures have been recreated on the holodeck?*

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/172598/20774) was posted about historic characters who've appeared (in TOS) **via means other than the holodeck**.

> Star Trek: TOS didn't have any newfangled, highfalutin' holler-decks.
>   Instead we had to make do with historical figures living through to
>   Starfleet times, or with aliens recreating famous people to try to
>   kill Kirk, Spock, McCoy, and various red shirts.

---

I flagged it as "not an answer" on the grounds that it ***does not attempt to answer the question*** but the flag has come back as "disputed" and the answer remains in place.

**If we don't like the question asked, can we just make up our own different questions and answer them?**

Comment: Worth noting that the original question (before you edited it) specifically mentioned TOS, in which holodecks hadn't been invented yet. Possibly a case of a **confused OP** rather than the answerer "making up their own different question".

Comment: @Randal'thor - That certainly doesn't change the fact that the question was about holodecks, not aliens.

Comment: @Randal'Thor regardless of the scope, it was asking SPECIFICALLY about holodecks.

Comment: Ugh, this site is going downhill. They'll let anyone moderate review queues these days. FWIW the review instructions didn't mention the NAA flag, so I hadn't read the question carefully. I said the answer looks OK because on it's own it was not low-quality/nonsense. Agree it is NAA though.

Comment: @zabeus - re-flag it then (if you can).

Answer (score 7):

In this instance, it appears the flag was marked disputed because its trip through the queue resulted in two "looks ok" and two "recommend deletion" reviews.

Remember, only Community♦ can dispute flags, based on the results of the review.

Comment: Just beat me to it! [Link to the review in question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/115194)

Answer (score -1):

This flag should not have been disputed. The answer in question is clearly not an attempt to answer *the question asked*, it's an attempt to answer *an entirely different question of the OP's own devising.*

Although it contains potentially interesting information, if the OP is interested in posting info about historic characters who've appeared in Star Trek outside of the holodeck, they should have posted a new question (perhaps "*which historical characters have been depicted in TOS*") and then self-answered that question instead of subverting this question.